# Divergence of an extrinsically defined vector field

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $M$ be a Riemannian manifold of dimension $n$ which is isometrically embedded in some Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^N$ (say by some embedding $\phi:M\to\mathbb{R}^N$). Suppose we have a smooth function $f:M\to\mathbb{R}$ and a fixed vector $w\in\mathbb{R}^N$.

I define a vector field $X:M\to TM$ by
$$X(m)=f(m)P_mw,$$
where $P_m:T_{\phi(m)}\mathbb{R}^N\to T_mM$ is defined by projecting from $T_{\phi(m)}\mathbb{R}^N$ to $\phi_*T_{\phi(m)}M$ and then seeing the result as an element of $T_mM$.

I would like to compute the divergence
$$\operatorname{div}(X)=\,???$$
but I am quite stuck. My differential geometry is a bit rusty, the extrinsic definition of the vector field stumps me quite a bit, and I was hoping someone here would have a good idea about how to proceed.

---

What I would expect to come out of this intuitively is something of the form
$$\operatorname{div}(X) = g(\nabla f,P_mw) + f(x)(\text{some kind of curvature term}).$$
The first term seems to come out quite naturally from the product rule, while the remaining term involves differentiating the embedding and I would expect it to give me indications of how the manifold bends in a direction or the other.

I am trying to work in special charts (eg normal coordinates around a point and possibly using an adapted orthonormal frame centered at the point) but with no success for now. I will update my question if I make significant progress.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $P \colon \iota^*(T\Bbb R^N) \to TM$ be the orthogonal projection, where $\iota\colon (M,g) \to (\Bbb R^N, \langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle)$ is an isometric embedding.
We use $\nabla$ for the Levi-Civita connection of $M$ and $\overline{\nabla}$ for that of $\Bbb R^N$.
Let $I\!I$ be the vector valued second fundamental form, defined by $I\! I(u,v) = \overline{\nabla}_uv - \nabla_u v \DeclareMathOperator{\trace}{trace}$.
Let $H$ be the mean curvature vector defined by $H = \trace (I\! I)$.
Let $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ be a local orthonormal frame on $M$.
We have $H = \sum_{j=1}^n I\! I(e_j,e_j)$ by definition.
Then
$\DeclareMathOperator{\Div}{div} \newcommand{\nablab}{\overline{\nabla}}$
\begin{align}
\Div(Pw)
&= \trace(\nabla (Pw)) & \text{by definition}\\
&= \sum_{j=1}^n g(\nabla_{e_j}(Pw),e_j) & \text{by definition}\\
&= \sum_{j=1}^n e_j\,g(Pw,e_j) - g(Pw,\nabla_{e_j}e_j) & \text{since } \nabla \text{ is metric for } g\\
&= \sum_{j=1}^n e_j\,\langle Pw,e_j\rangle - \langle Pw, \nabla_{e_j}e_j \rangle & \text{by } g=\iota^*\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle\\
&= \sum_{j=1}^n e_j\, \langle w,e_j \rangle - \langle w, \nabla_{e_j}e_j \rangle & \text{by orthogonality properties}\\
&= \sum_{j=1}^n \langle \nablab_{e_j}w,e_j\rangle + \langle w, \nablab_{e_j}e_j\rangle - \langle w, \nabla_{e_j}e_j \rangle & \text{since } \nablab \text{ is metric for } \langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle \\
&= \sum_{j=1}^n \langle w, \nablab_{e_j}e_j - \nabla_{e_j}e_j\rangle & \text{since } \nablab w = 0\\
&= \sum_{j=1}^n \langle w, I\!I(e_j,e_j)\rangle & \text{by definition} \\
&= \langle w, \sum_{j=1}^n I\!I(e_j,e_j)\rangle & \text{by linearity}\\
&= \langle w, H \rangle & \text{by definition}
\end{align}
(note that for these computations to be completely rigorous, one needs to extend $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ in a neighbourhood in $\Bbb R^N$ of their domain, and then evaluate on $M$.)
Now, notice that
$$
\Div(X) = \Div(fPw) = \trace(\nabla (f Pw)) = \trace (df \otimes Pw + f\nabla (Pw)) = df(Pw) + f \Div(Pw).
$$
It finally follows that
$$
\Div(X) = \langle \nabla f, w \rangle + f \langle w,H\rangle, 
$$
where we have used that $df(Pw) = g(\nabla f, Pw) = \langle \nabla f,w \rangle$.
Note that the curvature term is of extrinsic nature (it involves the mean curvature of the embedding $\iota\colon M \to \Bbb R^N$), and not intrinsic.

---

This formula is still valid for any isometric embedding $M \hookrightarrow N$ if $w$ is asked to be parallel in $N$ (or at least along $M$).
If $w$ is not parallel, there is some "horizontal ambient divergence" $\sum_{j=1}^n\langle \nablab_{e_j}w,e_j\rangle$ involved.

Comment: Thanks a lot Didier! I was trying to write everything in local coordinates but it was a hopeless mess. In my case the embedding is an isometric embedding, shouldn't that make the curvature term intrinsic as well by any chance?

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud What I wrote is for any isometric embedding already. Two isometric embeddings can have different extrinsic geometry, and this is what the second fundamental form is measuring. The mean curvature term will vanish for minimal embeddings though

Comment: Ah, I see. Great, thank you very much!

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud You're very welcome! I think you settled it: "everything in local coordinates" is "a hopeless mess" :-)

Comment: I will use the computation you provided in an upcoming article. If you want, I would be happy to say that it was communicated by you and cite your (full, real) name. Otherwise I will just cite this answer. Please let me know if you have a preference! You can find my email in my SE profile.

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud I sent you an email from my institutional address.